# How do i display an image on the browser using express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Am quite new to express js and I have this task am supposed to do at school.
I have tried other answers but all in vain.
Am having two servers, A and B both running on express js, I want server A to supply an image to server B and server B will display it to the client.
**How do I send the image the to server B and how do I display it to the client???** This is what I have tried but am not able display to d client side.

```
// server A
const appA = express();
appA.get('/processImg', function(req, res){
    // process image 
    // send  the image to server B
    res.sendFile(filepath)

});
```

This is the extract code for  server B

```
  // server B
    const appB = express()

    appB.get("/", function() {
      // make request to server A
       var image = undefined
       request.get('http://localhost:8084/processImg', (err, resp, body) => {
          if (err) return next(err);
          image = body;
        })

      // return the response to the client
       fs.readFile(image, (err, data) =>{
         res.write(image)
       });


    });
```

Any help will be highly appreciated, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

On server B:

```
 appB.get("/", function(req, res) {
   request.get('http://localhost:8084/processImg').pipe(res);
 });
```

Comment: this downloads the image insteady of displaying it, otherwise thanks

Comment: And how is it from server A?

Comment: you can change the headers `res.set('Content-Type', 'image/bmp/); // mimeType`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **Redirect** feature of `responseObject` in Express to redirect your request.

```
res.redirect('http://localhost:8084/processImg')
```

This will serve response directly from server A.